# View PDF file internally into the app from local folder by using inappbrowser

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am developing an app for ipad using

> ionic framework

I am stuck at one point were

> i want to open a PDF file using inappbrowser from an local folder

So that the user can read the PDF internally. The PDF is kept in local folder were my HTML file is available and i am trying to open it through below code:

```
    window.open('pdf-sample.pdf', '_blank', 'location=yes');
```

But the issue is when i am trying to open it i am

> not able to view/read the PDF file

It shows me the **white blank screen** with no content in it.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

What should i do to resolve this issue?

-thanks

Answer (score -1):

The code looks ok. Try to open https://www.google.com/. If that works than the path to pdf is not correct.

Are you sure you try to open after deviceready ?

Comment: yeap i am opening it after the deviceready and the pdf is in the same file where my html. there is no folder. so how can be the path incorrect. Is there any other way to pass path for app??? It works if i pass it any url. because even i used text file and it is working properly through local folder.

Comment: what happens when you try _system instead of _blank?

Comment: Nothing just it goes to safari and same response blank screen in that too. :(

Comment: have you tried saving the file to the phone/ipad and getting it from there?

Comment: in my app, i save pdfs and any other files to the phone and open them. bot on android and ios

Comment: I will try this and let you know what was the output for that.. :|

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I have used that but i dont want that output the way i m looking for is to get from local Source and display it.